# usb debugging, mono for android on vmware windows 8?

Tags: xamarin.android, vmware-fusion

I'm using the android emulator in this environment (VMware fusion5/windows 8/vs2012-mono for android) and it's working ok for degugging, but I'd like to switch a license to this machine so I can use it for actual device testing. Since you are limited with the number of times you can repurpose a license with xamarin, I'd like to know if it'll actually work before I activate the license on this environment. Anyone doing it?
Thanks.

Comment: Try it, you can always e-mail support if you run out of retries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone needs to know, it works fine. VMware sees the device when it's plugged in and asks if you want to connect to windows or mac. Choosing windows lets adb see the device.